# Micrometer to Prometheus conversion

Tags: prometheus, micrometer

I have a Spring Boot 2 application that uses Micrometer.

Unfortunately, I need to use [Prometheus PushGateway](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway) (i.e. pushing instead of pulling)

So I need to read all `Meter`'s from `MeterRegistry` and convert them to Prometheus objects (e.g. Gauge, Counter) . Then, register them to a `CollectorRegistry` and push them using `PushGateway`.

Is there a convenient way to make this conversion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set up that manual conversion at all. Just read up the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#production-ready-metrics-export-prometheus) regarding the Prometheus Pushgateway support in Spring Boots Actuator.